# How should I deal with a valid answer that also asks another question?

Tags: discussion

I came across this answer in the VLQ review queue:

> ```
> [UILabel sizeToFit];
> ```
>
> It will work for your problem.But one issue is that it creates allignment issues in arabic and Hebrew languages, anybody have any solution please help me. Thanks

I wasn't sure what to do so I skipped. It didn't seem appropriate to delete it as the first part does contain a plausible answer to the original question. However the second part should clearly be a new question. Someone had already added one of the canned "If you have a new question" comments so I've upvoted that. What else should I have done, edited out the extraneous bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, first things first: edit out the part that is obviously not an answer. The same way as you'd edit out noise like "Hey guys", "Thanks a lot", etc.

If there's still have an answer to the question somewhere in there when you get done editing, leave it be. On the other hand, if there's nothing resembling an answer, vote to delete it.

In this case, if you want to *improve* the answer, you should add a sentence explaining how or why this magic code fixes the problem. (You certainly don't have to do this, though—reviewers don't have to be experts on the subject matter of a post, so you might not even know yourself.)